# Can I rely on LogCat for sure

Tags: android, logcat

I am wordering if I can trust the LogCat.
So my question is:
Can I rely on the chronology of the LogCat?
Is it a 100% sequentially?

Comment: what are you trying to do with logcat ?

Comment: It is just a general question because I have some actions in a sequence and I was wondering if I could trust the LogCat.

Comment: logcat logs the thread id with the message. logs from the same thread are sequential. from different threads, it's another matter, and I would not count on it.

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat also includes a timestamp with each message. You should rely on that if you need things in temporal order.

Comment: I'm not sure about timestamps that are the same to within 1/1000th of a second...?

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that LogCat isn't a good solution for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Só it is not a 100% for sure?

Comment: Since applications can log from multiple threads, the concept of ordering is complicated. With the limited information you have given us, it is impossible to ascertain whether or not logcat will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If `record#1` appears in the log before `record#2` - you can be certain that the event corresponding to the `record#1` had happened before the event corresponding to the `record#2`.

Timestamps depend on the system time. And system time can be changed (for example synchronized with the external source) in between the events - so in general I would not rely on the timestamp order.

Also logcat timestamps have nanosecond resolution. But the only way to see it is to parse `logcat -B` output